# Can a Lore shaman with Arcane Enlightenment actually use Shadow Conjuration?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature

> Arcane Enlightenment (Su): The shaman's native intelligence grants her the ability to tap into arcane lore. The shaman can add a number of spells from the sorcerer/wizard spell list equal to her Charisma modifier (minimum 1) to the list of shaman spells she can prepare. To cast these spells, she must have an Intelligence score equal to at least 10 + the spell's level, but the saving throw DCs of these spells are based on her Wisdom rather than Intelligence. When she casts these spells, they are treated as divine rather than arcane. Each time the shaman gains a level after taking this hex, she can choose to replace one of these spells with a new spell from the sorcerer/wizard spell list.

This means he can choose it.

> You use material from the Plane of Shadow to shape quasi-real illusions of one or more creatures, objects, or forces. Shadow conjuration can mimic any **sorcerer or wizard** conjuration (summoning) or conjuration (creation) spell of 3rd level or lower.

Any spell a shaman casts will be a shaman spell, even if he got it by access to the sorcerer/wizard list.

Does that mean that those spells are useless for shamans (and other classes that might have a way to gain access to them)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**You can use *shadow conjuration***, and you can use it to imitate sor/wiz conjuration spells even though you can't cast them the ordinary way. This makes it even more useful for a shaman than for a wizard.

*Shadow conjuration* does not say you need to know the spells being imitated. It does not say they need to be on your class spell list. It says they have to be "sorcerer or wizard" spells. It continues to refer to "sorcerer or wizard" spells even if you're not a sorcerer or wizard.

This isn't even a weird edge case about off-list spell access, because *shadow conjuration* is also natively on the bard list and on the darkness domain. It's clearly intended to allow vanilla bards and clerics to imitate wizard conjuration spells.

Answer (score 5):

**No**

The class feature you're referring to allows you to add sorcerer and wizard spells to your spell list but it doesn't say anything about changing the spells' text to reference shaman instead of sorcerer/wizard.

When you cast shadow conjuration  you can specifically pull from the list of spells given, in this case:

> any sorcerer or wizard conjuration (summoning) or conjuration (creation) spell of 3rd level or lower.